# How do I get JSON result from controller to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, typeahead.js

I have a query result in controller which I encoded to `json`. I need to pass it to javascript, because I want to use `typeahead js` to autocomplete search input. This is my attempt:

My controller (Admin.php):

```
public function promotion()
{   
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("from_email");
    $this->db->from('booking');
    $query2 = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query2->result_array();
    $data['from_email'] = json_encode($results);

    $this->template->render('admin/promotion',$data,'admin');
}
```

My input search (to search based on email address from database):

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-lg typeahead typeahead-from-email" id="email" required="required" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" />
```

Javascript :

```
var emails = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('from_email');
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: base_url + 'admin/promotion'
});
$('.typeahead-from-email').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'from_email',
        displayKey: 'from_email',
        source: from_email
    });
```

It's not working.

Comment: What is expected result of `$data['from_email'] = json_encode($results);`?

Comment: I hope those aren't genuine email addresses...

Comment: The problem maybe that you are returning a rendering page rather than just the JSON itself. What does the template "admin/promotion" generate?

Comment: it loaded `header`, `content`, like the other page

Comment: Does `echo $data['from_email']` return expected result?

Comment: yes, it return all the user emails, `[{"from_email":null},{"from_email":"lalala@yahoo.co.id"},{"from_email":"myself@gmail.com"},...` @guest271314

Comment: `echo` to `.typeahed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call view or template

```
public function promotion()
{   
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("from_email");
    $this->db->from('booking');
    $query2 = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query2->result_array();
    echo json_encode($results); //<-- Just echo the json result
}
```

Then in your javascript

```
prefetch: <?php echo base_url('admin/promotion'); ?>
```

Comment: you're right, I just need one new function to encode the query result. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try this first to check if your typeahead is actually working then try searching "Ala" or "Cal". I'll update my answer based on your response.

```
var emails = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California']
});

$('.typeahead-from-email').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3
},
{
    name: 'from_email',
    source: emails
});
```

Comment: it's not working either :( it gives me no error also

Comment: do you use chrome dev tools? if yes then monitor your network tab while typing on your typeahead input and see if it's actually querying your server

Comment: yes, im using chrome, but it shows me nothing when I type search

Comment: i got this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function` `typeahead.bundle.min.js` when I start typing in the input text :(